# codeigniter setup can't access controller via url

Tags: php, codeigniter

Firstly i am new to codeigniter i did follow the steps of the docs and some yt videos but I can't seem to get codeigniter to work properly here is my issue

***1. My SetUp***
Server: Xampp :: localhost
My folder htdocs/crm/code files here

I changed my xampp 'httpd.conf'
from

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/">
```

to

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/crm/public/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/crm/public/">
```

so that i can access codeigniter via `http://localhost/` rather than `http://localhost/crm/public`

and i changed app\Config\App.php base url etc....

when I go to `localhost/` it shows me the codeigniter welcome screen same with `localhost/index.php` but when i try to type `localhost/home` it says ->

```
404 - File Not Found
Can't find a route for 'get: home'.
```

but home is a controller in my folder `app\Controllers\Home.php`

`home.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

It should be accessible via the url right? can anyone tell me what i might have done wrong? did i not configure something correctly.

Please understand i am new to codeignter not php but just the framework its my first time using it and if i need to supply more info or docs please comment and i will edit my Q

Thank you and have a great day :)

Comment: I'm not sure which version you are using but try to add `yourdomain/index.php/controllername`. Then it may work. The reason is simple, MVC frameworks start every request with index.php file.

Comment: You may find documentation saying how to remove index.php from codeigniter URL. You need to add .htaccess file with some configs available on codeigniter website and remove index.php inf config file perhaps.

Comment: you may follow this tutorial
https://programmingfields.com/how-to-remove-index-php-from-url-in-codeigniter-4/#:~:text=To%20remove%20index.php%20from%20URL%20in%20CodeIgniter%204,indexPage%20value%20and%20create%20.htaccess%20file%20with%20rewrite

Comment: Or maybe I'm wrong for codeigniter 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: `` This applies only to ver `4.2.1` as I have not tested the other versions ``

***First***
you have to go to `app/Config/Routes.php` then uncomment property `setAutoRoute(false)` and set it's value to `true` not `false` then go to `app/Config/Feature.php` and change the property `$autoRoutesImproved` to `true`

When no defined route is found that matches the URI, the system will attempt to match that URI against the controllers and methods when Auto Routing is enabled. - [Codeignter docs](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/routing.html#enabled-auto-routing-improved)

***Secondly***
A controller method that will be executed by Auto Routing (Improved) needs HTTP verb (get, post, put, etc.) prefix like getIndex(), postCreate().

Example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class Helloworld extends BaseController
{
    public function getIndex()
    {
        return 'Hello World!';
    }
}
```

Please note this is from my experience and according to `Codeignter` documentation, you can find the full article here: [Auto Routing (Improved)](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/controllers.html#controller-auto-routing-improved) and [URI Routing](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup routes in Codeigniter 4. `app/Config/Routes.php` file. There you may find this for new installation:

```
$routes->get("/", "Home::index");
```

Here you may define more routes like:

```
$routes->get("/hello", "Home::hello");
```

In `Home` controller you may say:

```
public function hello()
{
    return "Hello";
}
```

Comment: can this be done `auto` or should I enter a new line of code each time i create a controller it seems a bit weird.

Comment: I think i found it first i had to set setAutoRoute(true) in Routes.php then whenever i create a new controller a controller method that will be executed by Auto Routing (Improved) needs HTTP verb (get, post, put, etc.) prefix like getIndex(), postCreate().